# Excel with VB6.0

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

I am new to VB 6.0 ,I am trying to process text and xls files and placing the result in to Excel workbook.

Could you please anyone tell me how to create tabs in Excel sheet and place the content in that.

Regards,

Raju

Comment: I know this isn't a VBA question, but it is specific to Excel programming and that tag will get to the right people.

Comment: I suspect it is a VBA question. @Raju do you mean code within Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code to create a new sheet in VBA:

```
Dim oSheet As Worksheet Variant
Set oSheet = Worksheets.Add
```

If you need to manipulate the sheet (rename...), see [this link](http://excelvbamacro.com/create-new-excel-worksheet-with-vba.html)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way would be to open Excel, record a macro and select a sheet and enter some data. The VB 6 code will pretty much be the same code as in the recorded macro once You've set a reference to Excel from VB 6 (or you can use late binding and the createObject function).

Comment: Id ont know how  to create a sheet( As a tab) in the Excel work book .Please post me some code if you have it.